# w3 total cache minification breaks wp_localize_script()

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, wp-localize-script

I am trying to configure W3 total cache plugin to speed up my site. The minify option is great but I am running into the following issue:
Let's say I have a JavaScript file I am attached `wp_localize script()` to and it's called `'additions.js'`. Because W3TC minifies this JavaScript file and renames it, the `wp_localize_script()` function no longer sees my `'additions.js'` file and the variables inside it don't get shared with it.
Does anyone have a solution for this? Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

W3 Total Cache has 4 locations to include the minified files.  Since `wp_localize_script()` hooks into `wp_head()` (unless you specify in footer in your enqueue) you can use the `before </body>` minify location and your script will have access to the variables set.  On some occasions this has failed for me so I just exclude the script from minify.